# Bash: passing a variable to mv command option

Tags: bash, variables, mv

--Bash 4.1.17 (running with Cygwin)

Hello, I am trying to pass the date into the --suffix option on the move (mv) command. I am able to pass in a simple string (like my name) but unable to pass in the date. If you run the script below you will see that the mv command with the suffix="$var" works but suffix="$now" does not.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="your directory goes here"

now="$(date "+%m/%d/%y")"

var="_CARL!!!"

echo "$now"

echo "$var"

cd "$dir"

touch test.txt

# error if already exists
mkdir ./stack_question

touch ./stack_question/test.txt

mv -b --suffix="$var" test.txt ./stack_question/
```

The idea is that if test.txt already exists when trying to move the file, the file will have a suffix appended to it. So if you run this script with:

```
--suffix="$var"
```

you will see that the *stack_question* directory contains two files:

test.txt & test.txt_CARL!!!

But, if you run this script with:

```
--suffix="$now"
```

you will see that in the *stack_question* directory only contains:

test.txt

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your suffix has a slash in it. That's not legal in a filename. I'm not sure why `mv` is just silently ignoring that though.

Comment: @arco444 Not in a script it won't. History expansion isn't active there by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have embedded `/` in your date format try

```
now="$(date +%m_%d_%y)"
```